# How do I prevent Scheduled jobs from running twice?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-scheduled

I'm working on a Spring Boot application. This particular application is set up entirely using annotations, no config files. I must also mention that I am not an expert with Spring and I did not create this application; I've been tasked with maintaining it after the original authors left the company.

In any case, I added the @EnableScheduling annotation to what I guess is the class that initializes the application (public class ServerApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer). Then I created another class, annotated it with @Component, and annotated a method in that class with @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * *") to make it run once per minute.

The problem is that Spring launches two instances of the function every time the second hand reaches zero, instead of one. From what I'm reading this could be because there are two "contexts" created, but I don't really understand what a context is or how one gets created. I put a breakpoint in the configure method of the ServerApplication class and saw that it only gets called once.

Is this problem due to having more than one context? What causes a context to be created and why might I have two of them? Where should I look for clues?

Thanks,
Frank